# How to extract a method in eclipse that converts a field or constant value to a parameter

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

Situation: I'm working on legacy code and trying to improve readability. The following example should visualize the intent:

```
private static final String CONSTANT_1 = "anyValue";
private static final String CONSTANT_2 = "anyValue";
private static final String CONSTANT_3 = "anyValue";
private static final String CONSTANT_4 = "anyValue";
private static final String CONSTANT_5 = "anyValue";

private final SomeType someField = new SomeType();

private void contentOfSomeMethods(){
    someMethod(someField, CONSTANT_1, true);
    someMethod(someField, CONSTANT_2, true);
    someMethod(someField, CONSTANT_3, true);
    someMethod(someField, CONSTANT_4, false);
    someMethod(someField, CONSTANT_5, false);
}

private void someMethod(SomeType type, String value, boolean someFlag) { }
```

Imagine, there are about 50 calls of someMethod using about 50 constants. I want to do **safe automatical** refactorings on that code so that the `contentOfSomeMethods` method changes to

```
private void contentOfSomeMethods(){
    doItWith(CONSTANT_1);
    doItWith(CONSTANT_2);
    doItWith(CONSTANT_3);
    doItNotWith(CONSTANT_4);
    doItNotWith(CONSTANT_5);
}
```

and two additional methods are generated:

```
private void doItWith(String value) {
    someMethod(someField, value, true);
}

private void doItNotWith(String value) {
    someMethod(someField, value, false);
}
```

The naive way is to extract all constants in `contentOfSomeMethods` inside local variables and use then the extract method refactoring to create the desired methods. And afterwards to inline back the local variables. But this solution **doesn't scale up**.

Another way is to use search and replace with regular expressions, but this is **not a safe refactoring**, so I could break the code without noticing it.

Do you have any better suggestions? Do you know some plugins for Eclipse that allow that?

Comment: I think regex is the only way to go here. To minimize the chance of breaking unrelated code, you can make the changes only on a selection.

Comment: I fear you are right. The problem with regex is also the complexity. If there are three such constants per method it became quite difficult to write a regex ad hoc.

Comment: Would it be all right if I provide an answer with a regex and try to minimize the impact?

Comment: For me its OK. If there will be no better answer it will be quite helpful for other people who read this question, when they have at least one scalable solution.

Comment: Does save action actually mean safe action?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any utility that would do this directly.

I think using a regular expression is the only to go. First, you will need to create the two target methods `doItWith` and `doItNotWith`. Then, you can highlight the contents of the method `contentOfSomeMethods`, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, and use the following regular expressions:

> Find: `someMethod\(someField, (\w*), true\);` 
>   Replace with: `doItWith(\1);`

and then

> Find: `someMethod\(someField, (\w*), false\);` 
>   Replace with: `doItNotWith(\1);`

Be sure to check "Regular Expressions" and "Selected lines". Here's a picture of it:

[image]

The regular expressions match the constant that is used inside the function call with `(\w*)` and then it is used during the replacement with `\1`. Using this regular expression only on the selected lines minimizes the chance of breaking unrelated code.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with a regular expression and **verify** it.

I'm assuming that each call to `someMethod` spans only one line. If not this method is still useful but slower.

Copy the original file.

Use ctrl+alt+h to show the Callers of `someMethod` and get a count of them.

Do regex search and replaces restricted to the proper area :
Find : someMethod(someField,([ ]*CONSTANT_[0-9]+)[ ]*,[ ]*true[ ]*)[ ]*;
Replace : doItWith("$1");
Find : someMethod(someField,([ ]*CONSTANT_[0-9]+)[ ]*,[ ]*false[ ]*)[ ]*;
Replace : doItNotWith("$1");

Make a diff of the original file and the new file showing only the lines of the original file which have changed.

```
diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' original.java refactored.java | wc
```

You should get the same number of lines as you got in the callers of someMethod.

If the calls to someMethod are multiline, or if you want greater verification, just drop `| wc` to see the lines which were modified in the original file to ensure that only the correct lines have been modified.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It shows especially how the results can be verified. This may be quite helpful for real big classes. However *manual* verification should not be part of *automatical* refactoring. I hope to find a solution that can be applied without manual verification, because you can oversee something.

Comment: @Typischserg How many callers you get with ctrl+alt+h? What do you get from `grep someMethod source.java | wc`?

Comment: @Typischserg I strongly disagree with this statement: "However manual verification should not be part of automatical refactoring"

Comment: @Typischserg I strongly disagree with this statement: "However manual verification should not be part of automatical refactoring". You are responsible for the code you are committing, the tool is not. The refactoring tool can have bugs or it may have done something you did not expect. The rule of thumb is to always review your code before committing.

Comment: @JnRouvignac: I'm with you, when you talk about reviewing code before committing. However when you review about 200 changed lines, you can overlook somethink, so I wish a tool based rafactoring. And about "tool can have bugs" yes, but the compiler can have bugs, too so do you check the class files before providing your software to customers (not intended to be provocative)? I have the expectation that my tools works correctly. So I extend my statement: "However manual verification should not be part of automatical refactoring (but it still remains as a part of the commit workflow)"

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos It doesn't matter for the question. In the class were I started the refactoring and desided to post the question were 17 tests and each of them used the method 1-3 times. So to reduce duplication one of the first steps was to extract that methods. However I am in same situation quite often

Comment: Automatic refactoring without human intervention is better than that with human intervention. Because it leaves no space for human error. But after that fully automatic refactoring, you still do human verification; I think that is the point of JnRouvignac, to which I fully agree. @Typischserg I ask about the output of the grep | wc command and the count of the callers of the method because if they are equal it is possible to compose a tool to automatically refactor de code and automatically verify it. No point for me in doing that if not applicable tough.

Comment: "However manual verification should not be part of automatical refactoring (but it still remains as a part of the commit workflow)" => @Typischserg agreed, yes

Answer (score 0):

Alas I know nothing in Eclipse that allows to do this today.
This is something I would like to achieve one day in AutoRefactor: https://github.com/JnRouvignac/AutoRefactor/issues/8

However the road to get there is quite long.

The only ways I know today are to extract local variables then extract method (as you suggested) or use regexes (as somebody else suggested).